# Turn off background hover color on table in SharePoint wiki page

Tags: sharepoint-online, wiki-pages

In our SharePoint online we have several wiki pages containing tables. Whenever a user hovers over a cell of one of these tables, the background color of that cell changes. This gives the user the impression that the cell is clickable, although this is not the case.
Is there a way to turn off the hover event for all tables (without having to edit the source code of the page)?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to get rid of the hover -

1. Check and see using Chrome or any browser debugger tools if there
   exists any hover event
2. Identify the selector (ID or class) of the cell(s) where you wish to
   remove the hover (Lets say the class is "myHover"
3. Put in the code snippet in any Content Editor

   myHover:hover{
   pointer-events:none;
   }

Comment: That's the problem, I've tried this, but I cannot find a hover event inside the page. Maybe this is done on the site level?

Comment: Ok I see. Well, still go ahead and add the snippet forcefully. Add an "!important" too. If you do not find a class or id - try targeting the elements on some parent-child selectors. Let me know if issue still exists...

Comment: It's SharePoint Online, I don't know how to edit the code of the page. If I do this inside the Chrome debugger, then I cannot save the changes right?

Comment: You need to add a Content Editor Webpart somewhere on the page, to add the code snippet

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint doesn't add hover effects to table rows/cells by default. This would have been added as a customization after the fact. It can be done with CSS or with JavaScript, the latter which may explain why you don't see a hover class.

Using the browser inspector, look at the table HTML and see if there is an onMouseOver/onMouseOut event that has been added to the table cell/row code.

Additionally, SharePoint doesn't always use the `:hover` pseudo class for hover effects. Often SharePoint uses JavaScript to change the applied CSS class. For example the assigned class will be `ms-item`, then JavaScript is used to change the CSS class on mouseover to `ms-item-hover`. This is highly annoying because the only way to see them is to use a browser inspector and really watch the HTML code as you move around the page. Often the inspector will light up the changed code when there is a source code class swap like this.

Either way, there is no setting you can toggle to turn off table cell hovers. And any fix will involve editing the code. If this is a site wide issue and you are able to create CSS that fixes it, you can add a CSS file to your site and point to it via Alt CSS URL (Site Settings -> Master Page). This would be better than adding a content editor web part to every wiki page that is affected.

Also, please refrain from using `!important` in your CSS unless you are overriding an inline SharePoint style.

---

Heather Solomon, The SharePoint Experience